# Chrome: ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT on SSO

Tags: google-chrome, single-sign-on

I'm fixing now SSO bug, which appears on Chrome v.66.

The case: we have a chrome extension with implemented SSO login.
The process is:

1. Chrome extension performs redirect (opens a new tab) to our site SSO page. We pass encoded email and finish url as a query parameters;

2. SSO page redirects to SSO server and a user performs authorization there.

3. After response is ready SSO server performs redirect back to our site with corresponded token as a query parameter.

4. After the response is processed with our site, the redirect is performed to chrome extension and we're able to get the result of auth process.

The problem:
after step 3 (before step 4) Chrome blocks the redirect and shows the message:

This site can’t be reached

*The webpage at **<page>** might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
**ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT***

The url of the **<page>** is correct and it work ok, but Chrome blocks the request to the url.

On previous Chrome versions everything seems to work fine, but v. 66 breaks everything.

How could it be fixed? Is there any idea?

Comment: I'm suffering of the same issue, anyone has an idea on how to handle this?

Comment: Same issue here.... did you get any fixed ?

Comment: There was a bug filed [crbug.com/837909](http://crbug.com/837909)

Comment: Same issue.. trying to get GitHub OAuth working :/

Comment: same issue on Chrome 66. With AWS Cognito

Comment: In my case I was attempting to silent authente. I just decided that if it error'd out that meant that it was trying to redirect and I just manually redirect it myself to wherever I want within my chrome extension application. Not sure if that will help any of you, but if you have a better alternative, please share.